# I am trying to pluck the median from a json file using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Attempting to pull the mean value from the ages and handle a missing value in one of the ages.

```
var data={"users":[
{
"first_name":"Mikey",
"last_name":"Mouse",
"age": 24
},
{
"first_name":"Donald",
"lastName":"Duck",
"age": 29
},
{
"first_name":"Woody",
"lastName":"Woodpecker",
"age":
},
{
"first_name":"Bugs",
"lastName":"Bunny",
"age": 32
}  
]}
```

Comment: your code is missing

Comment: This code isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: Struggling t do two things. Get the median age of these fine legends and deal with the missing age on Woody Woodpecker.

Comment: Where's your code so far, and where specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: Here is my loop

Answer (score 0):

With [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#), you could do the following (no idea what libs you are using, you did not provide any code):

```
const ages = R.compose(R.map(R.propOr(0, 'age')), R.propOr([], 'users'))
const mean = R.converge(R.divide, [R.sum, R.length])
const meanAges = R.compose(mean, ages)

console.log(meanAges(data)) // 21.25
```

`R.propOr(0, 'age')` takes `0` as age, if no age is given.

```js
const data={"users":[
{
"first_name":"Mikey",
"last_name":"Mouse",
"age": 24
},
{
"first_name":"Donald",
"lastName":"Duck",
"age": 29
},
{
"first_name":"Woody",
"lastName":"Woodpecker"
},
{
"first_name":"Bugs",
"lastName":"Bunny",
"age": 32
}  
]}

const ages = R.compose(R.map(R.propOr(0, 'age')), R.propOr([], 'users'))
const mean = R.converge(R.divide, [R.sum, R.length])
const meanAges = R.compose(mean, ages)

console.log(meanAges(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.22.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow!! Folks, I am in humbled that you helped. I will absorb this info and read it over and over until it all makes sense! Thank you for ur direction!

Answer (score 0):

Remove people without a set age, then map to get ages only, then sort and return the medean:

```
function getMedeanAge(data) {
    let ages = data
        .filter(cartoon => cartoon.age !== undefined)
        .map(cartoon => cartoon.age)
        .sort((a,b) => a > b);

    var middleIndex = ages.length / 2;

    return ages[Math.floor(middleIndex)] + ages[Math.ceil(middleIndex) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nayish for taking the time to help!

Comment: please accept the answer if it worked :)  (and maybe +1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop approach with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) by collecting all values in `sum` and the count of valid `age`. Then you can get the average by division of the sum of all ages by `count`.

```js
var data = { users: [{ first_name: "Mikey", last_name: "Mouse", age: 24 }, { first_name: "Donald", lastName: "Duck", age: 29 }, { first_name: "Woody", lastName: "Woodpecker", age: null }, { first_name: "Bugs", lastName: "Bunny", age: 32 }] },
    sum = 0,
    count = 0,
    average;

data.users.forEach(function (user) {
    if (typeof user.age === 'number') {
        sum += user.age;
        ++count;
    }
});

average = sum / count;

console.log(average);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina! Much appreciated and will absorb all I can.